# Ubuntu partition unknown, cannot mount or update grub

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

After a power failure, I had the following error:

```
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

1. I ran the Ubuntu repair using a live usb. The log can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8464735/)
2. After this grub disappeared (I cannot select which OS to boot) and by default I am booting windows now. I have an important application running on Linux but I cannot boot to Linux.
3. I then edited the grub file and tried to update-grub but it says:

   ```
    failed to get canonical path of /cow
   ```
4. The next option was to `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt` But then I get the error:

   ```
    mount: you must specify the filesystem type
   ```
5. I do not know the filesystem type, since I did not do the installation on this particular machine.
6. I also tried `cat /etc/fstab` but it does not show sda5, neither can I see it using `blkid` command. From the GUI (since i have booted the system from live usb), I can see the partition 5 as having unknown type.

UPDATE: `fsck -a -t ext4 /dev/sda5` immediately gives the following error:

> fsck from util-linux 2.20.1 fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block
> while trying to open /dev/sda5 /dev/sda5:  The superblock could not be
> read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.
>
> If the
> device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem
> (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is
> corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate
> superblock: e2fsck -b 8193  or e2fsck -b 32768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

You must boot from a live-dvd/usb.

Open a terminal.

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fsck -a -t ext4 /dev/sda5
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
update-grub
umount /mnt
reboot
```

Comment: after fsck -a -t ext4 /dev/sda5 it immediately gives the following error:fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5: 
The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Comment: Welcome to AU! Please [include](https://askubuntu.com/posts/530575/edit) this info in your question.

Comment: I did this followed by what you mentioned above: sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda5 . Saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [rescue log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8464735/) and [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530575/ubuntu-unknow-partition-cannot-mount-or-update-grub#comment724506_530637) the header of the file system on sda5, your Linux partition, is seriously broken. You may be able to recover from the backup superblock as described in the output of `fsck` (from a live system [as described by kyodake](https://askubuntu.com/a/530637/175814)):

```
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda5
```

If that doesn't work, the file system is likely beyond repair. If you have important data on it, you can try to salvage it with data recovery tools, e. g. [as described in the community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract_individual_files_from_recovered_image).

Comment: Yes this worked followed by what Kyodake mentioned. Thanks. You guys saved us a lot of data ! :)